# Add OTP View in custom input view for UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

My `UItextField` has a custom number keyboard input view, how to integrate the auto capture OTP feature in the custom keyboard.

My code

```
let inputView = MyCustomInputView()
textField.inputView = inputView
inputView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view) it states cleary you cannot do that.

> Warning
>
> If you use a custom input view for a security code input text field,
> iOS cannot display the necessary AutoFill UI.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you should set the `.textContentType` property of your textfield to `.oneTimeCode`

```
textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

From Apple:

> The expectation that a text input area specifies a one-time code for
> delivery over SMS.

Comment: I believe the question is about the custom number pad.